# Issues in sharing Key and IV during encryption

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes

I have implemented the below AES algorithm in Java, but I the problem arises cause the encryption is performed at the design time and the decryption is performed at the runtime due to which, the decryption fails at runtime.

During decryption, the  IvParameterSpec and SecretKey are null as they are called at an entirely different time. How do I implement in such scenario?

```
static IvParameterSpec ivspec =null;
static  SecretKey secKey=null;

public static SecretKey getSecretEncryptionKey(){       
    KeyGenerator generator=null;
    try {
        generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    generator.init(128); // The AES key size in number of bits
    secKey = generator.generateKey();
    return secKey;
}


 public static String encrypt(String text) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }

     secKey = getSecretEncryptionKey();
     byte[] iv = new byte[128/8];
     Random randomNumber = new Random();        
     randomNumber.nextBytes(iv);
     ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

     Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
     ci.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey, ivspec); 
     byte[] byteCipherText = ci.doFinal(text.getBytes());
     return String.format("{%s}", base64Encode(byteCipherText));
}

public static String decrypt(String text)  {
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    if (!text.startsWith("{") || !text.endsWith("}")) {
        return text;
    }
     Cipher ci;
     byte[] bytePlainText =null;
    try {
        ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ci.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey,ivspec);
         byte[] decryptText=base64Decode(text);          
         bytePlainText = ci.doFinal(decryptText);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 


     return new String(bytePlainText,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: Nothing really to do with AES - this is a key sharing problem. You generate a key and encrypt a message; you then send that message to your friend User27855 - they generate a key and decrypt the message. Obviously that doesn't really work. So you need to _share_ the key and IV between the encryption and decryption. How you do that is pretty much irrelevant to AES.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I am aware of that, Sorry I should have formed the question in a better way. I have edited the question.

Comment: That said, even if everything is done inside the same JVM and the same execution of the program, the design is seriously flawed. Decryption only works if you have encrypted only once before (since every encryption generates a new key and a new IV, and replaces the previous one). Your encrypt and decrypt methods should take a secret key and an IV as arguments (just like Cipher.init() does, hint hint!). The program should generate those parameters and pass the same values to encrypt and decrypt. If the same key / IV must be used every time, generate them once once, then pass them to your methods

Comment: Mutable static fields is always a bad idea, and this time is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the algorithm as below:

To Obtain Secret Key:

```
private static SecretKey getKey() {

    System.out.println("Key Length " + KEY_LENGTH);
    try {
        return new SecretKeySpec(SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")
                .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(CIPHER_KEY.toCharArray(), CIPHER_KEY.getBytes(), 10000, KEY_LENGTH))
                .getEncoded(), "AES");
    } catch ( Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Encrypt Method:

```
public static String encrypt(String text) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }

    Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    ci.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKey(), getIvParameterSpec());
    return String.format("{%s}", base64Encode(ci.doFinal(text.getBytes())));
}
```

Decrypt Method:

```
 public static String decrypt(String text) {
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    if (!text.startsWith("{") || !text.endsWith("}")) {
        return text;
    }
    Cipher ci;
    byte[] bytePlainText = null;
    try {

        ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ci.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKey(), getIvParameterSpec());            
        bytePlainText = ci.doFinal(base64Decode(text));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    return new String(bytePlainText, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```